# Magento sorting in cateory listing page

Tags: magento-1.7

I got the following code here:app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php and i got the following function. 
Can we add more code here to solve the issue.:--
Products should sort like:-

> 

Products Name: Prices

```
A:  $200

BC:  $200

B:  $100

BD: $100

CD: $100

C:  $99
```

```
     public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
  /*   if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    } */

    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='price'){
            $this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id','asc');
        }
        else {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I want to display products listing of category from high to 
low price if prices of all the products are same then all the products will be shown alphabetically by default on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got the answer:

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        if($this->getCurrentOrder()=='price')
        {
        $this->_collection->setOrder('price','asc');
        $this->_collection->setOrder('name','asc');
        }
        }
        else {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
    return $this;
}
```